# System error 85 has occured in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm executing a batch file from SQL Server using this code:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
reconfigure
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell','1'
reconfigure

exec xp_cmdshell '" D:\network.bat"'
```

and the `neywork.bat` contains the below commands

```
rem disconnect and re-set upn network drive connection
net use z: /d /yes
net use z:\\mlisfile07
```

Here the `z:` is mapped to some other path, but in the output it is showing as

> *network connection could not be found
>
>   system error 85 has occured*

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space between the drive letter and the network path:

```
net use z: \\mlisfile07
         ~~~
```

Comment: I have kept the space  and tried. the commands are executing when i hav execute them from command prompt, but they are showing errors when executed from sql server

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that your logged in SQL-SERVER user doesn't have administrative permissions.

Please review : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253821.